# "local variable referenced before assignment" but assigning the variable is the first thing i do

Tags: python, local-variables

I'm in a beginner Python class and my instructor wrote pseudocode for us to follow. I've followed it to a T (I feel) and have been getting bugs no matter how I try changing the program. I'd rather have my mistake quickly pointed out than spend more time mucking about. This is written in Python 2.7.8.

```
#Anthony Richards
#25 February 2018
#This program is a simple simulation of an order-taking software.
#It demonstrates multiple variables, functions, decisions, and loops.

def main(): 

    declareVariables()

    while keepGoing == "y":

        resetVariables()

        while moreFood == "y":
            print "Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger"
            print "Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries"
            print "Enter 3 for Soda Yum"
            option = input("Please enter a number: ")
            if option == 1:
                getBurger()
            elif option == 2:
                getFries()
            elif option == 3:
                getSoda()
            else:
                print "You've made an incorrect entry. Please try again."
            moreFood = raw_input("Would you like to order anything else? (y/n): ")

    calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFries, totalSoda)
    printReceipt(total)
    keepGoing = raw_input("Would you like to place another order? (y/n): ")

def declareVariables():
    keepGoing = "y"
    moreFood = "y"
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFries = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    subtotal = 0
    tax = 0
    total = 0
    option = 0
    burgerCount = 0
    fryCount = 0
    sodaCount = 0

def resetVariables():
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFries = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    total = 0
    tax = 0

def getBurger(totalBurger):
    burgerCount = input("Please enter the number of burgers: ")
    totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount * .99

def getFries(totalFries):
    fryCount = input("Please enter the number of fry orders: ")
    totalFries = totalFries + fryCount * .79

def getSoda(totalSoda):
    sodaCount = input("Please enter the number of drinks: ")
    totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09

def calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFries, totalSoda):
    subtotal = totalBurger + totalFries + totalSoda
    tax = subtotal * .06
    total = subtotal + tax

def printReceipt(total):
    print "Your total is $"+str(total)

main()
```

Comment: When you declare variables in your functions, those variables are local to that function and will not be accessible from outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def func():
    x = "this is not global"

func()

# print(x) would throw an error

def func2():
    global y
    y = "this is global"

func2()

print(y) # This indeed will print it
```

Although you can use this, this is very, very bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes. You define the variables, but they only exist in `declareVariables`. Simply move the references over to inside the function you want (`main`) so they can exist there. Better yet, merge *all* the functions into one big one, so you don't have to worry about this (or have them all exist in the global scope [defining them *before* any functions are defined])